# Getting response from android PHP login

Tags: php, forms, authentication

I'm trying to determine whether the user name and password I've sent to a php login form is valid.  I've read some posts that suggest looking at the response text and checking for the title of the page that is returned.  Other posts mention using a session ID in some way.  Just what is the best way to detrmine if the user name/password combo is valid once I've posted to the form?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Update...

I was able to resolve this issue using the following code snippet:

```
response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
cookies = ((AbstractHttpClient) httpClient).getCookieStore ();
myCookie = cookies.getCookies ();
//  if cookies are empty, login did not work.
if (!myCookie.isEmpty ()) 
    { 
    for (int i = 0; i < myCookie.size(); i++) 
          { 
        String str = myCookie.get(i).toString(); 
        //  look for PHP session cookie and save it.
        if (str.contains ("PHPSESSID"))
            {
            phpsessid = myCookie.get (i).toString ();
            int index = phpsessid.indexOf("value");
            phpsessidGuid = phpsessid.substring(index+7, index+39);
            }
          } 
    }
```

Hope this helps others with the same problem.

Comment: Is the PHP login form written by you? Can you modify it? What response do you get on successful login (try from your web browser)?

Comment: I did not write the PHP for the Web site, but, I have access to the person who did.  He thought the best way would be to use the session ID.  I'm just not sure how to get it or use it.